# Why jquery DataTable() taking long time to populate 10,000 records?

Tags: jquery, datatables, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on Jquery DataTable() library but one thing i found it takes long time to populate if data array is more than 10,000.

```
 var newTable = '';
 var ref = firebase.database().ref("Students/");

 ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {

        var usn = data.val().usn;
        var name = data.val().studentName;
        var colname = data.val().collegeName;
        var branch = data.val().branch;
        var batch = data.val().batch;   

        newTable+='<tr data-value='+studentUsn+' id='+studentUsn+' class="home_list_bar">';
        newTable+='<td id="student '+studentUsn+'" class="home_list_border"><span id="studentid" class="home_list_item">'+studentUsn+'</span></td>';
        newTable+='<td class="home_list_border"><span id="studentname" class="home_list_item">'+studentName+'</span></td>';
        newTable+='<td class="home_list_border"><span id="branchname" class="home_list_item">'+studentBranch+'</span></td>';
        newTable+='<td class="home_list_border"><span id="branchname" class="home_list_item">'+studentBatch+'</span></td>';
        newTable+='</tr>';
        document.getElementById('tableDiv').innerHTML=newTable;
    });
    $('#user_table').DataTable().draw();
 });
```

So in the above code firebase will return around 10,000 student records and i am populating in the table view but as the data array size is more than 10,000 it takes lot of time to populate.

Please go through my post and let me know if you have any solution.

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to use server-side processing - take a look at this (https://medium.com/how-to-firebase/firebase-data-structures-pagination-96c16ffdb5ca#.gp4ghyin9) post and the links in particular (https://github.com/deltaepsilon/firebase-paginator). This alongside a look at this (https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) will probably see you right.

Answer (score 1):

`child_added` event is called for every record, so in your case it will be called 10000 times and 10000 you call the code in the listener which is not efficient . This is not good in terms that you can do better.
I recommend to change this into `once` or `value` event depending on what you prefer (read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)).

```
ref.on('once', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {

    var usn = data.val().usn;
    var name = data.val().studentName;
    var colname = data.val().collegeName;
    var branch = data.val().branch;
    var batch = data.val().batch;   

    newTable+='<tr data-value='+studentUsn+' id='+studentUsn+' class="home_list_bar">';
    newTable+='<td id="student '+studentUsn+'" class="home_list_border"><span id="studentid" class="home_list_item">'+studentUsn+'</span></td>';
    newTable+='<td class="home_list_border"><span id="studentname" class="home_list_item">'+studentName+'</span></td>';
    newTable+='<td class="home_list_border"><span id="branchname" class="home_list_item">'+studentBranch+'</span></td>';
    newTable+='<td class="home_list_border"><span id="branchname" class="home_list_item">'+studentBatch+'</span></td>';
    newTable+='</tr>';
    document.getElementById('tableDiv').innerHTML=newTable;
  });
  $('#user_table').DataTable().draw();
});
```

This is much more efficient. But anyway 10000 record is not small amount. Think about paginating the data.

Answer (score 0):

For large data set, you should use ajax loaded datatable. You will query for certain amount like 10 - 100 data & will execute it within a short time. You can check this [links](https://github.com/jobayerccj/jQuery-dataTable-SSP-class-with-union-option/) where I have added join & union with datatable query.